# Python. pytest не могу не находит функцию

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as chrome_options

@pytest.fixture
def get_chrome_options():
    options = chrome_options()
    options.add_argument('chrome')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--window-seze=800,600')
    return options

@pytest.fixture
def get_webdriver(get_chrome_driver):
    options = get_chrome_options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def setup(request, get_webdriver):
    driver = get_webdriver
    url = 'https://www.macys.com'
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.get(url)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

```
________________ ERROR at setup of TestHomepage.test_homepage _________________
file E:\python\test_homepage.py, line 9
      def test_homepage(self):
E       fixture 'setup' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_na
mespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attr
ibute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

E:\python\test_homepage.py:9
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR test_homepage.py::TestHomepage::test_homepage
============================== 1 error in 0.12s ===============================
```

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('setup')
class TestHomepage:



    def test_homepage(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Фикстуры в файле conftest.py или импортируются в test_homepage.py? Или в самом файле test_homepage.py?

Comment: фикстуры в conftest.py

Comment: Приведите код самого файла test_homepage.py

Comment: У меня ругается что нет фикстуры get_chrome_driver (у вас в коде действительно такой фикстуры нет), если заменить get_chrome_options, то тест проходит.

Comment: я тормаз, можете подсказать на что?

Comment: В строке `def get_webdriver(get_chrome_driver):` заменить get_chrome_driver, которого нет, на get_chrome_options

Comment: Не работает, пишет нету фикстуры 'setup'

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в коде, также в названии файла:
Было = conftast.py
Надо = conftest.py

Comment: "Achievement": Ник оправдан...